# Writing cookies via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies, popup

I am using this code to open an html pop up, to which is wish to add a "don't show again" button that will store a preference in a cookie so that the pop up won't be shown again
Why isn't it working?

this is the line that should write the cookie:

```
document.cookie = "dontShow=1; path=/; expires=Wednesday, 01-Jan-2020 12:00:00 GMT; domain=.qpcftw.co.cc";
```

**Update:** the problem is that the cookie isn't stored, and the "alert(document.cookie);" (see below) shows that the cookie is null (nothing is shown).

Here's the full JS code:

```
/***************************/
//@Author: Adrian "yEnS" Mato Gondelle
//@website: www.yensdesign.com
//@email: yensamg@gmail.com
//@license: Feel free to use it, but keep this credits please!
/***************************/
var popupStatus = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
        if (document.cookie != "dontShow=1; path=/; expires=Wednesday, 01-Jan-2040 12:00:00 GMT; domain=.qpcftw.co.cc"){
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.75"
        });
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#popupContact").fadeIn(1000);
        popupStatus = 1;
        }
    //CLOSING POPUP
        //Don't show again
        $("#dontShow").click(function(){
            document.cookie = "dontShow=1; path=/; expires=Wednesday, 01-Jan-2020 12:00:00 GMT; domain=.qpcftw.co.cc";
            alert(document.cookie); //4debugging
            disablePopup();
        });
        //Click the x event!
        $("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
            disablePopup();
        });
        //Click out event!
        $("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
            disablePopup();
        });
        //Press Escape event!
        $(document).keypress(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
                disablePopup();
            }
        });
});

//disabling popup with jQuery magic!
function disablePopup(){
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if(popupStatus==1){
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut(500);
        $("#popupContact").fadeOut(500);
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cookies are new to me, let alone local storage =/

Comment: and it seems like overkill, isn't it?

Comment: `localStorage` is easier to use. Writing/reading cookies is a pain. It's not an overkill. It's cookies 2.0.

Comment: It would help if you could you specify "not working". What happens, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message? Have you checked if the cookie gets stored in the browser?

Comment: simplest way is use jquery with "jquery cookie plugin"
`if($.cookie('dontShow')) ... else ...`

Comment: Thanks! i'll check out the query cookie plugin, but for now i'll update my answer with what actually goes wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uKwrM/)

```
document.cookie = 'dontShow=1; expires=Wed, 01 Jan 2020 12:00:00 GMT; path=/';

function readCookie(option) {
    var optionEQ = option + '=';
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];

        while(c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        }

        if (c.indexOf(optionEQ) === 0) {
            return c.substring(optionEQ.length, c.length);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

if (!readCookie('dontShow')) {
    //run your popup code
}
```

**Edit:** Or, as a custom jQuery plugin:

[**Plugin version Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uKwrM/1/)

```
document.cookie = 'dontShow=1; expires=Wed, 01 Jan 2020 12:00:00 GMT; path=/';

(function($) {
    $.fn.readCookie = function(option) {
        var optionEQ = option + '=';
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

        for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];

            while(c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            }

            if (c.indexOf(optionEQ) === 0) {
                return c.substring(optionEQ.length, c.length);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
})(jQuery);

if (!$(document).readCookie('dontShow')) {
    $('#cookie-status').html('<p>Cookie not set.</p>');
} else {
    $('#cookie-status').html('<p>Cookie has been set.</p>');
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I figured it out with jquery :) what does the '!' in 
if (!readCookie('dontShow')) {
    //run your popup code
} mean?

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX `!` is the `not` operator. The code basically says `if not read cookie dontShow` - in other words, if the cookie does not exist or has not been set (it was unable to read it, so it's not set), it would run your popup code.